# Database retreival as string in android

Tags: android, database

I have to retreive a string from database using their id.I done thet retreival,But it is returning as some object format not as a string.Please help me..

My retreival place:

```
db.open();
     for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
     {       
     if(i==1)
         group1=db.getspintitle(1);
     if(i==2)
         group1=db.getspintitle(2);
     if(i==3)
         group1=db.getspintitle(3);
     if(i==4)
         group1=db.getspintitle(4);
     if(i==5)
         group1=db.getspintitle(5);     
     }
```

db.getspintitle() method:

```
public String getspintitle(int rowId)throws SQLException
{

    String sumtotal="";
    Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(
             "SELECT spin from spinner WHERE _id='rowId'", null);  
     sumtotal=cursor1.toString();   
     cursor1.close();       
     return sumtotal;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your information, The below returns you the `Cursor`, not the simple String.

```
Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT spin from spinner WHERE _id='rowId'", null);
```

To retrieve value from the cursor, you have to iterate through the cursor.

Now, here in your case, you can do as below:

```
 Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT spin from spinner WHERE _id='rowId'", null);  

     if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
         cursor.moveToNext();
         sumtotal= cursor.getString(0);
         cursor.close();
     }
```

Comment: Yes Paresh Mayani. How can i convert them into string..Y because i have to set this value to textview in my screen..

Comment: Check updated answer. Keep this thing in mind because you also has to iterate cursor to fetch data.

Comment: @prakash.k yes the above code will return you the single value. If you want to iterate through the cursor, then you have to iterate this cursor.

Comment: LIke this r u saying..for(int i=1;i<=cursor1.getCount() ;i++)
 {
 if (cursor1 != null && cursor1.getCount() > 0)
 {          cursor1.moveToNext();         
 sumtotal= cursor1.getString(i);          
 cursor1.close();    
 } 
 }
  return sumtotal;                IT shows error..likr bad request..

Comment: @prakash.k please try to debug your program. You are on right way.

Comment: I have done R&D for you. [Android - iterate through the cursor](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=android+iterate+through+the+cursor&oq=android+iterate+through+the+cursor)

Answer (score 0):

```
  String[] sumTotal= new String[cursor.getCount()]
   while(cursor.moveToNext())
         sumtotal[i] = cursor.getString(0);
```